# How to run Show Column Query for Multiple Table in MySQL Php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a very simple question when i run the below query

```
 SHOW COLUMNS FROM `mytable` /*Its works*/
```

but when i run this

```
 SHOW COLUMNS FROM `mytable`, `mytable2` /*It doesnt work*/
```

can someone tell me how cani run Show column query for Two or more than two tables in mysql php

Comment: It seems you can't do that this way.

See http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/116861-show-columns-from-multiple-tables-not-possible/

Comment: than ...which way should i go?

Answer (score 2):

`SHOW COLUMNS` displays information about the **columns in a given table.**

Short answer is no, but the long answer is, "Yes, if you have the `information_schema` database installed.

**<kbd>[Information Scheme](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/columns-table.html)</kbd>**

Comment: @user2176667 please refer link i gave in answer it will explain more precisely than me..

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM yourtable FROM yourdb;
```

COLUMNS is for a given table only.  Use the info_schema tables in MySQL 5

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'database' 
AND (TABLE_NAME ='my_table' OR TABLE_NAME = 'my_table2')
```

where 'database' is your database name.